# permission to access users only on specific user group

Tags: permissions, user-groups

I would like to ask if there is a permission to view and edit the users on specific user group? or is there any plugin to do that?

example: I have user groups called **"Class 1"** and **"Class 2"** and I want to create permission that can only view and edit the user group **"Class 1"**.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is indeed possible in Craft 4.x, not sure about 3.x.
See screenshot.
[image]